# Leaflet.js: Use ctrl + scroll to zoom the map & Move map with two fingers on mobile

Tags: leaflet

I'm using http://leafletjs.com/ ... is it possible to only:

1. Use ctrl + scroll to zoom the map
2. Move map with two fingers on mobile/tablet

... so similar what google maps does? With the comments ...

So far thats my setup:

```
// Leaflet Maps
var contactmap = L.map('contact-map', {
        center: [41.3947688, 2.0787279], 
        zoom: 15,
        scrollWheelZoom: false
    });
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111887/leaflet-mouse-wheel-zoom-only-after-click-on-map a very similar solution to your ctrl + scroll

Comment: I really would dig a leaflet plugin that just does what google map does - IMHO it has a perfect solution (drag with two fingers for mobile, ctrl-scroll for desktop).

Comment: A leaflet plug-in is now available! https://github.com/elmarquis/Leaflet.GestureHandling https://stackoverflow.com/a/49366253/350421

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is an amazing library that does exactly that. [Leaflet.GestureHandling](https://github.com/elmarquis/Leaflet.GestureHandling)

It is an add on to leaflet that works right of the box, it's also modular and can be installed using npm.

Here's a working example using leaflet and GestureHandling.
You can try it also on mobile.

P.S. It has multiple languages baked in:)

```js
// Attach it as a handler to the map

const map = L.map('map', {
  gestureHandling: true
}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

// Add tile layer
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
    #map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 400px;
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
        crossorigin=""/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/leaflet-gesture-handling/dist/leaflet-gesture-handling.min.css"
        type="text/css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"
          integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
          crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/leaflet-gesture-handling"></script>
  
  
  
  <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Incorrect [Behaviour in Microsoft Edge](https://github.com/elmarquis/Leaflet.GestureHandling/issues/39) is yet to be resolved.

Comment: Does folium have this?

Comment: As far as I know, Folium is a Python wrapper to leaflet. 
I guess it should work, you'll just need to find out how to make it work together

Answer (score 8):

zoom map using ctrl + zoom. I did in custom way .
html code is below

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

css

```
.map-scroll:before {
content: 'Use ctrl + scroll to zoom the map';
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 999;
font-size: 34px;
 }
 .map-scroll:after {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
content: '';
background: #00000061;
z-index: 999;
}
```

jQuery

```
  //disable default scroll 
  map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

  $("#map").bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
     if (event.ctrlKey == true) {
             event.preventDefault();
         map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
           $('#map').removeClass('map-scroll');
         setTimeout(function(){
             map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
         }, 1000);
     } else {
         map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
         $('#map').addClass('map-scroll');
     }

 });

  $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
       $('#map').removeClass('map-scroll');
  })
```

In simple way when user scroll on map then detect ctrl button is pressed or not then just I add one class that will showing message on map. and prevent screen zoom-in and zoom-out outside of map.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to solve your second problem.

I used css for displaying the message using a `::after` pseudo selector.

```
#map { 
  &.swiping::after {
    content: 'Use two fingers to move the map';
  }
}
```

And javascript to capture the touch events.

```
mapEl.addEventListener("touchstart", onTwoFingerDrag);
mapEl.addEventListener("touchend", onTwoFingerDrag);

function onTwoFingerDrag (e) {
  if (e.type === 'touchstart' && e.touches.length === 1) {
    e.currentTarget.classList.add('swiping')
  } else {
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove('swiping')
  }
}
```

It checks if the type is a touchevent and if you are using 1 finger, if so it adds the class to the map with the message. If you use more than one finger it removes the class.

[Working demo](https://s.codepen.io/surisdziugas/debug/LzXPwz/yokZEQvqWGjA) I suggest you using a mobile device.

[Code pen from the demo](https://codepen.io/surisdziugas/pen/LzXPwz)

Comment: Mind that you should set map.dragging = false to prevent one-finger panning

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use `touchmove` instead of `touchstart` to avoid displaying message on tap